# What is the Best Way to Reproduce this Wavy Script in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

[image]

I would like to reproduce the "W" in W(E) from the screenshot above. How should I do this in LaTeX?

Comment: That's `\mathcal{W}`.

Comment: @Marjin Thanks!